# PowerBI custom combined column with Text.Combine and with embeded conditions leading to the insertion of different strings

Tags: powerbi, conditional-statements, concatenation, powerquery, m

I created a custom column in PowerBI, which concatenate columns.

I have the following:

```
Text.Combine({[Nip],[Nap],[Noup]]},"_")
```

However, I would like to have a specific text which change based on whether or not data is present in columns. I need to check if there is data in four columns. If there is data, a specific string of character should be inserted, if there is not, no data should be inserted.

I am trying to insert the outcome of the "IF"s, but there is some complexity, I have tried this, but this is not working, Power BI is telling me "Token Eof expected" :

```
If [Lapino] <> null or [Lapinou] <> null or [Werwolf] <> null or [Ciocolato] then 

Text.Combine({[Nip],"Snoubadiuba",[Nap],[Noup]},"_")

else Text.Combine({[Nip],"BruttoCativo",[Nap],[Noup]},"_")
```

Comment: Should there be a missing 'or' between null [Werwolf]? Or is it a typo on the question?

Comment: Yes ! I am sorry it is indeed a typo. I updated the question. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is as simple as changing your `If` to lowercase `if`. M code is case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes !!! Exactly. This is exactly this ! Thank you ! However, after making progress on that point, I also had several errors telling me cannot convert "null" to logical or cannot convert a figure in string. I had to apply the conversions. However, I wonder how not to do that again, because the input file will have this type of "null" when it will gez uploaded. So I am wondering how to automate this as well.

Comment: That sounds like a separate question.

Comment: Yes ! Thank you !